# How to efficiently pass or ignore some tokens resolved by a python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am applying a function to a list of tokens as follows:

```
def replace(e): 
    return e


def foo(a_string):
    l = []
    for e in a_string.split():
        l.append(replace(e.lower()))
    return ' '.join(l)
```

With the string:

```
s = 'hi how are you today 23:i ok im good 1:i'
```

The function foo corrects the spelling of the tokens in `s`. However, there are some cases that I would like to ignore, for example 12:i or 2:i. How can I apply `foo` to all the tokens that are not resolved by the regex:`\d{2}\b:i\b|\d{1}\b:i\b`? That is, I would like that `foo` ignore all the tokens with the form `23:i` or `01:e` or `1:i`. I was thinking on a regex, however, maybe there is a better way of doing this.

The expected output would be:

```
'hi how are you today 23:i ok im good 1:e'
```

In other words the function `foo` ignores tokens with the form `nn:i` or `n:i`, where `n` is a number.

Comment: Do you want to ignore all `':e'` tokens?

Comment: @DanielMesejo yes all the `nn:e` tokens, where `n` is a number

Comment: @anubhava I updated the question.

Comment: Your output is the same as your input

Comment: What is `replace`?

Comment: I updated with more details @DanielMesejo. yes because my function corrects the spelling of a string. However, is correcting cases that I would not like to be corrected. Thats the reason I would like to ignore tokens with the aforementioned form.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew spell checks a token

Comment: Add a `replace` placeholder something like the identity function `def replace(e): return e` to your question, so the code works

Comment: ok @DanielMesejo

Comment: I believe you are asking for https://ideone.com/SeQaWf. But I do not understand the point.

Comment: Or, if `N:i` and `N:e` are to be avoided, use https://ideone.com/T3tuz2. Could you please provide an input string that will change as a result of the replacements?

Comment: That's what I expected @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @anon Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

def replace(e): 
    return e

s = 'hi how are you today 23:i ok im good 1:e'
rx = r'(?<!\S)(\d{1,2}:[ie])(?!\S)|\S+'
print(re.sub(rx, lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else replace(x.group().lower()), s))
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/4hgniw) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FiUi1j/1).

The `(?<!\S)(\d{1,2}:[ie])(?!\S)|\S+` pattern matches

- `(?<!\S)(\d{1,2}:[ie])(?!\S)` - 1 or 2 digits, `:` and `i` or `e` that are enclosed with whitespaces or string start/end positions (with the substring captured into group 1)
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Once Group 1 matches, its value is pasted back as is, else, the lowercased match is passed to the `replace` method and the result is returned.

Another regex approach:

```
rx = r'(?<!\S)(?!\d{1,2}:[ie](?!\S))\S+'
s = re.sub(rx, lambda x: replace(x.group().lower()), s)
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/PORCvH) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FiUi1j/2/).

**Details**

- `(?<!\S)` - checks if the char immediately to the left is a whitespace or asserts the string start position
- `(?!\d{1,2}:[ie](?!\S))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is 1 or 2 digits, `:`, `i` or `e`, and then a whitespace or end of string should follow
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = ' '.join([i for i in s.split() if ':e' not in i])
```